# Conditionally perform assertion

Tags: jmeter

I would like to perform an assertion on a sampler only if certain conditions are met (i.e. variables and parameters have a specific value). The assertion should be ignored if the conditions are not met, not fail.

What are my options?

An if controller does not seem to work as it apparently requires the sampler (which always should be invoked) to be in its scope too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of using [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) which allows you executing arbitrary [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code providing maximum flexibility.

Here is an example simple code:

```
if (vars.get('foo') == 'bar') {                            // execute only if JMeter Variable ${foo} is equal to "bar"
    if (!prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains('baz')) { // if there is no "buz" word in the response
        assertionResult.setFailure(true)                   //fail the sampler
        assertionResult.setFailureMessage('Failed to find word "baz" in the response')
    }
}
```

Check out [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) article for more information.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I ended up using two If-Controllers, however, repeating the sampling and assertion logic in its scope.